# Custom filter for mtgox depth api request

Tags: mtgox, api

I am looking at [mtgox api documentation](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/MtGox/API/HTTP/v1) and specifically at Multi Currency depth http://data.mtgox.com/api/1/BTCUSD/depth/fetch

It returns back the list of **asks** and **bids** and a filter criteria like this:

```
filter_min_price: {
    value: "42.25504",
    value_int: "4225504",
    display: "$42.26",
    display_short: "$42.26",
    currency: "USD"
},
filter_max_price: {
    value: "51.64504",
    value_int: "5164504",
    display: "$51.65",
    display_short: "$51.65",
    currency: "USD"
}
```

Is it possible to apply the custom filter and get the filtered response from the server? Say if I wanted a smaller min/max price range. Can this be done in the API request?

I understand I can filter the response on the client after I get all the data, but was looking for a way to do it via api

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Mt.Gox

Answer (score 1):

On the v2 api, It's not possible, I guess, but they say [here](https://bitbucket.org/nitrous/mtgox-api/overview#markdown-header-moneydepthfetch) that it is, but that arguments to do so are not known. if you try any arguments the response is:

```
"error":"Invalid call method, please ensure query string is empty (min,max)"
```

that's why I think you can't, I guess it's the same for v1. Maybe you should think to do what you wanted to do another way, maybe updating your data with `trades/fetch?since=1364767190000000`